# How to prove a set is compact in one metric space iff it's compact in another

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

I'm trying to prove that a set (called K) is compact in metric space (Rn,d1) IFF it's compact in (Rn,d2) where:
d1 = E|x-y|
d2 = (E(x-y)^2)^1/2

Apologies for not knowing how to markup the equations correctly. So, I've proven that if d1 is compact, then d2 is compact. But I'm having trouble with the other direction. My initial idea revolved around proving that somehow d1 is contained in d2. But there's been no progress there. Could use some help. Thanks.

Comment: It should suffice to show that a ball of radius 1 in one space both contains a ball of *some positive radius* from the other space and also is contained in a ball of *some positive radius* from the other space.

Comment: Thank-you @GregMartin. That's a new direction I'll follow! Might have to ask more.

Comment: @GregMartin just to confirm, when you say "other", you mean the same ball right? So I need to prove that a ball of space A (for example) contains a ball in space B, but that ball A is also contained in a larger ball of B. That's how I've interpreted your stmt.

Comment: Two metrics are equivalent (generate the same topology) if there exists positive constants  $a,b$  such that $ad_2(x,y)\leq d_1(x,y)\leq bd_2(x,y)$.   Note this is essentially the same as Greg's hint above

Comment: @Alan Thanks for the info. So using your inequality, I found out that a and b bookend a value greater than or equal to 1. Using GregMartin's insight, can I say that we can always find the containments that he mentioned?

Comment: See this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for the preferred mathematical markup on MSE.

Comment: @robarthan thankyou!